# Window function ignores order if there is unused named window in the query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, window-functions, mysql-8.0

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  `SchoolName` VARCHAR(10),
  `Marks` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO tablename
  (`SchoolName`, `Marks`)
VALUES
  ('A', 71),
  ('A', 71),
  ('A', 71),
  ('B', 254),
  ('B', 135),
  ('B', 453),
  ('B', 153);

SELECT
    *
FROM
    (  
        SELECT 
            SchoolName,
            Marks,
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY SchoolName ORDER BY Marks) rn
        FROM tablename
        WINDOW w  AS (PARTITION BY SchoolName ORDER BY Marks)
) t
```

Does it ok that `rn` is unsorted if there is unused named window in the query with order by clause?

```
SchoolName  Marks   rn
A           71      1
A           71      2
A           71      3
B           254     1
B           135     2
B           453     3
B           153     4
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pWH7ar9V8JLQ6FzM9Qd9K6/1

**EDIT**

I suppose it to be like this

```
SchoolName  Marks   rn
A           71      1
A           71      2
A           71      3
B           135     1
B           153     2
B           254     3
B           453     4
```

**EDIT 2**

OK, I have a little bit confused others, the problem is not with order of rows but why rn has value 1 next to 254 if I specified the order for `row_number()`.

P.s. I uderstand if I delete `window w` it will work well but why the unused named windows affects other window function?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Simply using the window function won't guarantee the order of the results.  The order is always _arbitrary_ unless you use an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: In fact, the first answer shows how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Your query defines a `window` frame that is not used - that part is just a no-op.

These are equivalent:

```
SELECT 
    SchoolName,
    Marks,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY SchoolName ORDER BY Marks) rn
FROM tablename
```

And:

```
SELECT 
    SchoolName,
    Marks,
    row_number() OVER w rn
FROM tablename
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY SchoolName ORDER BY Marks)
```

I don't see the point for using a subquery either - so I removed that part.

Note that the `ORDER BY` clause applies to the window function only. Both your query and the above two offer no guarantee about the ordering of the rows in the resultset itself. If you want a consistent ordering in the resultset, then use an `order by` clause, as in:

```
SELECT 
    SchoolName,
    Marks,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY SchoolName ORDER BY Marks) rn
FROM tablename
ORDER BY SchoolName, Marks
```

Comment: sorry that I left subquery there, the query is more complicate 

>Note that the ORDER BY clause applies to the window function only.

Ok, but does the 1 has to be next to 135 ?